# Telegram Bot Not Returning Channel Details When Channel ID is Entered

Tags: python, flask, youtube-api, telegram-bot, ngrok

I am currently working on a Telegram bot that takes a channel ID as input and should return the channel details. However, when I enter a channel ID on Telegram, nothing happens. I am using ngrok on port 5000 for local development. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request
from telegram import Bot
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define the route for the Telegram webhook
@app.route('/YvaBot', methods=['POST'])
def telegram_webhook():
    update = request.get_json()
    if 'message' in update:
        process_message(update['message'])
    return 'OK'

# Create a function to process incoming messages
def process_message(message):
    chat_id = message['chat']['id']
    if 'text' in message:
        channel_id = message['text']
        channel_details = get_channel_details(channel_id)
        send_message(chat_id, channel_details)

# Create a function to get channel details using the YouTube API
def get_channel_details(channel_id):
    # Set up the YouTube API client
    api_service_name = 'youtube'
    api_version = 'v3'
    developer_key = 'DEVELOPER_KEY'
    youtube = build(api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=developer_key)

    # Retrieve channel details
    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part='snippet,statistics',
        id=channel_id
    )
    response = request.execute()

    # Parse the response and extract relevant details
    channel = response['items'][0]
    title = channel['snippet']['title']
    description = channel['snippet']['description']
    subscriber_count = channel['statistics']['subscriberCount']

    # Create a formatted string with the channel details
    channel_details = f"Channel: {title}\nDescription: {description}\nSubscribers: {subscriber_count}"

    return channel_details

# Create a function to send messages to the user
def send_message(chat_id, text):
    bot = Bot(token='BOT_TOKEN')
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)

# Start the Flask development server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

I have ensured that I have the correct developer key and bot token in the code. However, when I enter a channel ID on Telegram, the bot does not return any channel details. I would appreciate any assistance in identifying the issue and resolving it. Thank you in advance!